# Lost github commit to gh-pages when checkout master

Tags: git, github, version-control, github-pages

After working on a repository in my computer i've opened the terminal to commit the changes to the github account with the purpose of updating the gh-pages branch (after 4 days of work).
I did not notice that I was on gh-pages branch already when a did the `git status` so I did as if I where on branch master.That is what I did:
1. `git add -A`
2. `git commit -m "message"`
3. `git push origin master`
After this I noticed that I was doing this in the gh-pages branch so I thought (not very cleverly) that i should go back to branch master to do the commits also there and then i did `git checkout master`. In that moment all my files (my local files, in my computer) went back in time!
The terminal showed a commit number when I did the first commit [gh-pages 4108d5a] but i can not find it in the github history.
Is there a way to recovery the previous state in my local files?? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you pushed to the wrong branch, and then changed branches.  You should be able to do this:

`git checkout gh-pages`

`git push origin gh-pages`

and all of your work should still be on gh-pages.  The master branch is right where you left it back in time.  But nothing you mentioned should have removed from your gh-pages branch.

A good resource to get comfortable with how git branching, merging, etc... work is [learn git branching](http://pcottle.github.io/learnGitBranching/)

Comment: Thanks @ChadF that worked!! I choosed that way because I knew the commands but i asume it's a good idea to merge both branches now, no?

Comment: Yes, if you'd like put the things you've done onto the master branch, merging would be the next step.  So, do the following: `git checkout master`, `git merge gh-pages`.

Answer (score 1):

provided you didn't delete `gh-pages` you can do

```
git checkout gh-pages
```

and then to recover your work

```
git reset head~1 --soft
```

or you may very well merge your branch into `master` like:

```
git merge gh-pages
```

Comment: Thanks @JSelser . I'm a little bit afraid. I do not see the previous commit in the history on git-hub nor in my computer. Do I proceed whit your answer??

Comment: Your commit should be safe in the `gh-pages` branch. For maximum safety go with `git merge gh-pages` instead of the reset. Try `git log` afterwards to check if the commit is there, you can undo any of the operations. Proceed, I'll guide you if it doesn't work.